# Run out of storage on Service Fabric scale set

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I've run out of storage on my Azure Service Fabric sclesets, so can no longer deploy any updates. I'm guessing this is because SF is keeping track of all the deployments and using up space.

Can anyone tell me if there is:

1) A way to tell service fabric to delete old deployments (say older than 10 days ago.)
2) A way to increase the storage available on the scalesets (Service Fabric is currently using the OS disk for deployments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your first question,

There is no way to tell SF to auto-delete old packages based on days, you can either:

- Do upgrades using the flag `-UnregisterUnusedApplicationVersionsAfterUpgrade = $true` when running the *Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1* script
- Update the *Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1* script or create a scheduled script to check for unused packages older than a specific version, something like described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45467800/strategy-to-unprovision-old-applicationtype-versions-in-service-fabric) SO

Regarding the second Question:

- Yes you can change the disk size via ARM template update,

But the issue might also be the LOGs size, take a look in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42379769/utilize-managed-disk-for-service-fabric-temporary-storage) question might help solve the problem without bigger disks.

Comment: I think the -UnregisterUnusedApplicationVersionsAfterUpgrade = $true should be enough for what I want. I checked the Log folder and that didn't seem particularly large.

Comment: If we are deploying our application through ARM, what is the ARM template equivalent of UnregisterUnusedApplicationVersionsAfterUpgrade?

Comment: @RyanY https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.servicefabric/clusters?tabs=json#applicationtypeversionscleanuppolicy-object